# How do I insert a user picture's thumbnail on the "Submitted by" field?

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I want to insert user picture's thumbnail on "Submitted by" field, which is displayed in teaser such as the following.

> Submitted by [some_user] [someuser picture's thumbnail] on xx/xx/xx

How do I do that as effortless as possible?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried playing with main theme's node.tpl (see the code sniplet below) , but nothing's happened. <br/><br/>  Before:<br/><code> <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <footer class="submitted"><?php print $date; ?> -- <?php print $name; ?></footer>
  <?php endif; ?> </code> <br/><br/>After:<br/><code> <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <footer class="submitted"><?php print $date; ?> -- <?php print $name; ?><?php print $user_name; ?></footer>
  <?php endif; ?> </code>

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7 you can achieve this using **template preprocess functions** - THEMENAME_preprocess_node.

Steps

- First add default user picture, go to sites/default/files and create a folder **user_pictures** and add default user picture by name **default.png**
- Now add default picture URL using **admin/config/people/accounts**.

  [image]
- Add this code in template.php

```
    function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
      $node = $variables['node'];
      if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') { //check for teaser views
        //get author picture uri
        $author_picture_uri = db_query("
        SELECT uri FROM {file_managed} fm
        INNER JOIN {users} u ON u.picture = fm.fid 
        WHERE u.uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $node->uid))->fetchField();
        $author_picture_uri = !empty($author_picture_uri) ? $author_picture_uri : 'public://default_user.jpg';
        $usr_pic = theme_image_style(
          array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $author_picture_uri,
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'author-pic'),
        'width' => NULL,
        'height' => NULL
          )
        );
        if ($variables['submitted'] && isset($node->uid)) {
          $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username !userpicture on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!userpicture' => $usr_pic, '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
        }
      }
    }
```

- Where `public://user_pictures/default.png` equivalent to `sites/default/files/user_pictures/default.png`

Comment: Thank you @inizio, I've tried the above code and clean all the caches, but  the original "Submitted by"(without user picture) is still there . Checking by DSM values show that  user picture's thumbnail has been included in $variables['submitted'].  Do you have any further suggestion ?

Comment: Why is Markdown is not working for me ??????

Comment: You have any default user picture? If not then add the default user picture. I have updated my answer. If there is no user picture then it will display default user picture.

Comment: thanks again @inizio,I did what you suggested,still no pictures though.by the way, when I changed the following line FROM     "$variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by ...." TO "$variables['submitted'] = t('Created by...." and clear the caches,the former (submitted by..) is shown, so I doubt if hook_preprocess_node is the right way to do this.

Comment: FYI @inizio, I am using Display Suite Module, from what i searched on the internet, the method you are suggesting does not work with DS module.